# Re-wrote gulpfile.js for Gulp 4 and default task hangs now

Tags: javascript, gulp-4

I upgraded from Gulp 3.9.1 to Gulp. 4.0.1 and now when I run it I see `"Starting 'default'..."` and nothing else happens. Here's the end of my gulpfile:

```
gulp.task('default', function() {
  gulp.watch('app/styles/**/*.scss', gulp.series('sass')),
  gulp.watch('app/*.html', gulp.series('browserSync')),
  gulp.watch('app/js/**/*.js', gulp.series('browserSync'));
  return
});

// Optimization Tasks 
// ------------------

// Optimizing CSS and JavaScript 
gulp.task('useref', function() {

  return gulp.src('app/*.html')
    .pipe(useref())
    .pipe(gulpIf('*.js', uglify()))
    .pipe(gulpIf('*.css', cssnano()))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
});

// Optimizing Images 
gulp.task('images', function() {
  return gulp.src('app/images/**/*.+(png|jpg|jpeg|gif|svg)')
    // Caching images that ran through imagemin
    .pipe(cache(imagemin({
      interlaced: true,
    })))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/images'))
});

// Copying fonts 
gulp.task('fonts', function() {
  return gulp.src('app/fonts/**/*')
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/fonts'))
})

// Cleaning 
gulp.task('clean', function() {
  return del.sync('dist').then(function(cb) {
    return cache.clearAll(cb);
  });
})

gulp.task('clean:dist', function() {
  return del.sync(['dist/**/*', '!dist/images', '!dist/images/**/*']);
});

// Build Sequences
// ---------------

gulp.task('build', function(callback) {
  runSequence(
    'clean:dist',
    'sass',
    ['useref', 'images', 'fonts'],
    callback
  )
})
```

I've tried rewriting my code a few different ways and I've gotten various errors. The furthest I've gotten is with passing `done` into functions and running the `done` function at the end of some gulp tasks, but I understand that I should be able to use Gulp 4 without taking that route.

Comment: I'm confused by what's going on with the `.series()` expressions. Each series only has one task, I don't see task functions for 'sass' or 'browserSync', and there seems to be some redundancy that's addressed in the [docs](https://gulpjs.com/docs/en/api/series#forward-references).

Comment: I got rid of the `series` expressions at the beginning and rewrote my `default` task so it reads:

`gulp.task('default', gulp.series(gulp.parallel('sass', 'browserSync'), 'watch'));`

Now BrowserSync launches in my browser and it says "BrowserSync: connected" in the upper right for a moment when it does, but it's not actually updating the page when I edit my index.html file.

Comment: It looks like the `watch` task never starts; I don't see `Starting 'watch'...`

Comment: I noticed you're using the comma operator (`gulp(),gulp(),gulp()`) rather than separate expressions (if that's the right way to say it: `gulp(); gulp(); gulp();`). I'm not sure that it's a problem, but that combine with not calling the `done()` callback stand out.

Answer (score 0):

change default code

```
gulp.task('default', function() {
  gulp.watch('app/styles/**/*.scss', gulp.series('sass')),
  gulp.watch('app/*.html', gulp.series('browserSync')),
  gulp.watch('app/js/**/*.js', gulp.series('browserSync'));
  return
});
```

**into To this**

```
function watch() {
    browserSync.init({
        server:{
            baseDir: './'
        }
    });
    gulp.watch('./scss/**/*.scss',style);
    gulp.watch('./**/*.html').on('change',browserSync.reload);
    gulp.watch('./scss/**/*.js').on('change',browserSync.reload);

}

exports.watch = watch;
gulp.task('default',watch  );
```

hope this will helps ..!

Comment: I tried this fix. Now BrowserSync launches in my browser and it says "BrowserSync: connected" in the upper right for a moment when it does, but it's not actually updating the page when I edit my index.html file. Thank you for taking a shot at my problem.

Comment: Have you check  file  path , i think thats the issue ... browserSync working but path was not correct